# What formula should I use if I were to search up with a specific criteria to return a value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example sheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Dy-VKL7xHlH5KpZnJkWjNPDM6g5lkKZReakyJGTdj0/edit#gid=605445197

Hello, I am fairly new to sheets and I was wondering what I should use for the following case:

1. I have a list of classrooms, each assigned with a class and its class code,
2. I have a dropdown list based on the list of classrooms,

For such case, what should I use if I wanted to return the assigned class and class code based on the value select from the dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the formula I just added to that sheet.  It's:

```
=iferror(index(C:C, match(H4, B:B, 0)), "")
```

INDEX returns a row from an array* when given an index.  MATCH returns the index of the matching record from an array.  0 means exact match, but there are other options.

In my opinion, INDEX+MATCH is superior to VLOOKUP, which is what a lot of people use.

* actually, just one cell, but the column reference is optional and people usually pass single column arrays to it.  If you define a multi-column range for the first argument of INDEX, you can specify the row and column, either of which you can determine with MATCH, which makes INDEX+MATCH very versatile.

Comment: Thanks! I assume I can use this with arrayformula so I wouldn't have to type that formula for each row?

Comment: Now that I am not sure of BUT if you make the references appropriately dynamic or static as needed, you can just drag or copy it over the entire range.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I3:I6, B3:F, {2, 4}, 0)))
```

[image]

and:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I8:I, B3:F, IF(J8:J=C2, {2, 4}, {3, 5}), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: @Michael answer updated

Comment: That's cool! Thanks!